# The default remember_me token in Laravel is too long

Tags: laravel-5.4

TL;DR How can I use my own way of generating the remember_me token?

I have an old site, written without any framework, and I have been given the job to rewrite it in Laravel (5.4.23). The DB is untouchable, cannot be refactored, cannot be modified in any way.

I was able to customise the Laravel authentication process using a different User model, one that reflect the old DB. But when it comes to the "Remember me" functionality, I have an issue with the length of the token.

The old site already uses the "Remember me" functionality but its DB field has been defined as BINARY(25). The token generated by the SessionGuard class is 60 characters long.

My first attempt was to try and find a way to shorten the token before writing it into the DB, and expand it again after reading it from the DB. I couldn't find such a way (and I'm not even sure there is such a way).

Then I looked into writing my own guard to override the cycleRememberToken (where the token is generated). I couldn't make it work, I think because the SessionGuard class is actually instantiated in a couple of places (as opposed to instantiate a class based on configuration).

So, I am stuck. I need a shorten token and I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was on the right track at one point.

I had to create my own guard, register it and use it. My problem, when I tried the first time, was that I did not register it in the right way. Anyway, this is what I did.

I put the following in AuthServiceProvides

```
Auth::extend('mysession', function ($app, $name, array $config) {
  $provider = Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']);

  $guard = new MyGuard('lrb', $provider, app()->make('session.store'));

  $guard->setCookieJar($this->app['cookie']);
  $guard->setDispatcher($this->app['events']);
  $guard->setRequest($this->app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest'));

  return $guard;
});
```

I change the guard in `config/auth.php` as

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'mysession',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

and finally my new guard

```
class MyGuard extends SessionGuard implements StatefulGuard, SupportsBasicAuth
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function cycleRememberToken(AuthenticatableContract $user)
    {
        $user->setRememberToken($token = Str::random(25));

        $this->provider->updateRememberToken($user, $token);
    }

}
```